# Does Views RSS display deals with relationship

Tags: feeds, views

I have a content type "Event" which has a relationship with the content type "Category", via the node reference field 'category_ref'.

The "Category" content has a field "Image".
I have figured out how to display the field "Image" in a page view listing the "Events" node, with relationship option on "Image" field.

It works just fine, except that I would like now to create a feed for this view, to export it on Facebook. But then, as there is no field to set up for RSS feed, I don't know how to fetch the image from "Category" and get it in my RSS.

The point where I'm stuck is that the relationship is set on the RSS display tab, but the image does not show.

Is there a way to do fetch datas from another content type than the one of the views via the RSS display of the Views interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [Views RSS](https://drupal.org/project/views_rss) module.  It will add a new plugin that will allow you to map arbitrary fields to RSS elements at the channel and item level.

[image]

So, if your view is fielded out with the proper relationships already, you can just add a new display, map the fields, and assign it to a path, all in about 10 min.

[image]

The help in the module is also excellent.

Comment: Oh dear, 
it is what I need indeed. 
I have tried it and get the image displayed in my <enclosure> tag easily enough. 
It does not address the problem that RSS graffiti does not retrieve the image in its preview, though, so I guess I will have to try another to have it in another tag. Thank you anyway for your help, and the screenshots which was very helpful!

Comment: @Mat Double check the field settings.  You may need to adjust to be plain text in a few places, and use absolute URLs for the link and enclosure.

Comment: I have changed the image formatter accordingly to "plain_text_metatags", it has removed the markup around my link. And I've set absolute URL for both field "link" and "image". Finally, I get the URL of my picture wrapped by <enclosure> tags. But it does not seems to change anything on RSS graffiti. It seems to me it is the proper way format for the enclosure tag. Isn't it?